# Unexpected indent on main method

Tags: python, python-click

I can't see anywhere where there is extra whitespace or unnecessary indenting in this. This is beyond frusterating. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
def main():
    """ This is a simple EC2 Command line tool"""
    @click.group()
    @click.option('--ami', default='ami-0de7daa7385332688', help='What AWS AMI are you using?')
    @click.option('--instancetype', default='t2.micro', help='AWS EC2 instance type')
    @click.option('--vpc', help='VPC ID')
    @click.option('--isweb',default=True,help='Is this a web server')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators are specified *before* the class/method/function definition, see the [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).

So in your case:

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--ami', default='ami-0de7daa7385332688', help='What AWS AMI are you using?')
@click.option('--instancetype', default='t2.micro', help='AWS EC2 instance type')
@click.option('--vpc', help='VPC ID')
@click.option('--isweb',default=True,help='Is this a web server')
def main():
""" This is a simple EC2 Command line tool"""
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```